# How do I change my account password?

Tags: support

The Help Center only has information on [resetting a lost password](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/reset-password):

> I lost my password; how do I reset it?
>
> If you have lost your password, please visit our [account recovery page](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery) and enter the email address that you signed up with. We will email you a list of your account credentials and a link to reset your password.

Comment: Of course, resetting your password this way will change it.

Comment: You could accept sumelic's answer otherwise the question will probably be bumped to the front page (next month) by the community bot for lack of upvotes and/or answers.

Answer (score 2):

From your [profile page](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/210913) on the main site, click on the following options:

Edit Profile & Settings > My Logins > change password